# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS does not see Windows 10 partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows, external-hdd

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the external hard disk (1 TB size). I have a laptop with Windows 10. Windows 10 is set on the 512 GB disk. After entering Ubuntu, I can't see (access) the Windows 10 partitions. Somewhere on the Internet someone wrote that the possible solution is turning off quick start of Windows. I turned off quick start in BIOS and also in Windows power settings but it didn't help. In Ubuntu, I opened "disks" tool, and it shows me the Windows disk with partitions but there is no information (it writes "Unknown") about file system of two partitions (partition 3 and partition 4) which correspond to "C" (system files) and "D" (data). I attach the prtscr of "disks" window. Please advise me what I can do to solve this problem.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

[image: image5]

[image: image6]

Comment: Disable Fast startup in Windows and Secure Boot in BIOS

Comment: have you ever manipulated your partitions within windows? - if yes, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296447/93768) may match.

Comment: I disabled Fast startup in Windows and Secure Boot in BIOS however the problem isn't solved - Windows partitions aren't seen within Ubuntu. And one more problem appeared after installing Ubuntu. Now when I try to start Windows 10, it requires the BitLocker key, and every time when I want to enter Windows, I need to go to the official site (using my mobile phone) where I can get the BitLocker key (my laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon). So should I decrypt Windows disks now? May the encryption cause the problem with access to Windows partitions within Ubuntu?

Comment: I haven't manipulated my partitions within Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I coped with two problems by disabling the BitLocker encryption in Windows. So now I can enter Windows without any BitLocker recovery key and I can see Windows partitions within Ubuntu (in the launcher). I attach the prtscr of "disks" tool in Ubuntu - the information about Windows partitions appeared (file system NTFS is recognized).

But one more problem occured (I don't know when this chain of problems finishes). From time to time, when shutting down (or restarting) either Windows or Ubuntu, my laptop doesn't shut down, it suspends (or may be "hangs" will be more correct to say), the screen becomes black and nothing happens. In this case, I have to push and hold power button in order to turn off computer. What can cause such a trouble? May it be somewhat related to USB connection by which the external hard disk is connected to the laptop?

[image: screenshot of partitions]